# PipeWire volume-change with pw-cli doesn't notify other programs

Tags: python, pipewire

I am trying to change PipeWire audio volumes via my Python script. Since there isn't, at the time of writing this, a simple Python library for PipeWire, I am doing that by calling the *pw-cli* utility via Python

The problem is that while it works in changing the volume, other programs that monitor volume changes don't reflect that (wpctl's status output, my tray volume indicator or volume monitor program like Pavucontrol). When I inspect the PipeWire properties of my sink via *pw-dump* or *pw-cli*, it shows the changed volume.

When I use WirePlumber's *wpctl* to change the volume, it works as expected. The change gets picked up by my tray volume indicator, Pavucontrol or wpctl's status report itself.

What does *wpctl* do differently than *pw-cli*? What's the proper way to change the volume with *pw-cli*? I could call *wpctl* via Python, but that would create another dependency (WirePlumber) which I thought I could avoid.

Here are the exact lines I'm using:

```
# changes volume, but not picked up by other programs
pw-cli s 54 Props "{channelVolumes: ["0.2", "0.2"]}"
```

Here's the relevant pw-dump and pw-cli output showing the change:

```
$ pw-cli e 54 Props
  Object: size 1136, type Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Props (262146), id Spa:Enum:ParamId:Props (2)
    Prop: key Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Props:volume (65539), flags 00000000
      Float 1,000000
    Prop: key Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Props:mute (65540), flags 00000000
      Bool false
    Prop: key Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Props:channelVolumes (65544), flags 00000000
      Array: child.size 4, child.type Spa:Float
        Float 0,200000
        Float 0,200000
```

```
$ pw-dump 54
...
"Props": [
          {
            "volume": 1.000000,
            "mute": false,
            "channelVolumes": [ 0.200000, 0.200000 ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does ID **54** correspond to a node? If so, with `pw-cli s 54 Props "{channelVolumes: ["0.2", "0.2"]}"` you are setting the volume relative to the device volume

To change the volume you need to change the *Route* parameters using the *route index* and *route device*.

```bash
# pw-cli e <device-id> Route
...
 Prop: key Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Route:index (1), flags 00000000
      Int <route-index>
...
Prop: key Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Route:device (3), flags 00000000
      Int <route-device>
...
```

the volume goes between 0 and 1.0 and you have to apply the cubic root.
for example to set the volume to 50% = 0.5^3 = 0.125

```bash
pw-cli s <device-id> Route '{index: <route-index>, device: <route-device>, props: {channelVolumes: [0.125, 0.125], mute: false}}'
```

```bash
# wpctl get-volume <node-id>
Volume: 0.50
```

---

Script to set volume (**jq utility required**)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Extract the partial name of the default device
device_partial_name=$(pw-metadata | grep "key:'default.audio.source'" | awk -F"'" '{print $4}' | sed 's/\\//g' | jq .name | awk -F"." '{print $2}')

# Retrieve the device ID using pw-dump and jq
device_id=$(pw-dump Device | jq '.[].info.props|select(."device.name" | contains('\"$device_partial_name\"'))' | jq '."object.id"')

# Dump route information and extract index and device for the specified device ID
route_values=($(pw-dump $device_id | jq '.[0].info.params.Route[0]| (.index, .device)'))

# Extract route index and profile
route_index=${route_values[0]}
route_device=${route_values[1]}

# Set the desired volume level
VOLUME=0.125 # 0.5^3 = 50%

# Use pw-cli to set the route properties including channel volumes and mute status
pw-cli s $device_id Route "{index: $route_device, device: $route_device, props: {channelVolumes: [$VOLUME, $VOLUME], mute: false}}"
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!



How would I go about finding or verifying the proper ID to use? My former way involved querying the metadata information for default sink. That's how I got the "wrong" ID, i.e. the _PipeWire:Interface:Node_ object. Your solution is to use the the _PipeWire:Interface:Device_ corresponding to my sound card. I can however see multiple _PipeWire:Interface:Device_ types.

Would querying for metadata for default sink and comparing its _alsa.card_ to a _PipeWire:Interface:Device_'s alsa.card key be a good approach?

Comment: I cannot post the full output of pw-dump unfortunately.  
What would be a good approach to figure out which object/device's route settings to change? Ideally I want this to work on other setups/computers as well.

Comment: Add a script that can help you. You cannot check how it will behave with more than one device (sound card).

Comment: Anything add your `pw-dump` to the original question.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot add the pw-dump to my original question since it's too long. The script you added helps though, it gives me a rough outline how to approach it in a sane way. Thanks.